# Azure ARM Json File Missing

Tags: azure

I have a VM that I need to move between subscriptions. I've tried following https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-capture-image/
and I now have the vhs in a blob container - as shown below.

[image]

My problem is - I don't have the Json template file that the description says I should have (and need to restore the VM to the target subscription)

> Double-click Microsoft.Compute > Images, which will show you all of your image folders. Double-click the folder name that you entered for the destinationContainerName variable while capturing the image from Resource Explorer. It will show you both the VHD, as well as the JSON template file.

Could anyone please suggest what step I may have missed or how I can obtain the Json template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json file is emitted by the Save-AzureRmVMImage cmdlet. It is a convenience but is not needed. You know where the image VHD and you can use it directly using the template as an example https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-from-user-image